# How can I get price list to line up?

Tags: html, css, text, line

On the following website, I am trying to get the prices to line up evenly so that the word "up" is not uneven as you go down the page. Basically I want the words on the right to be nice and straight like how it is on the left. I have tried justifying the text, but that does not work.  Here is a screenshot:

[image: better screenshot]

Comment: This may or may not be spam, but you've provided a link that looks like it would go to a commercial site, and you haven't shown any code here (HTML, CSS, etc.) that show you've actually got a programming problem.  Please show code and a screenshot, not a link to an external site.  I've taken a screenshot of the site and replaced the link with it.

Comment: why not add `float: right;` to the price class.

Comment: @user Dude, why don't you just use a Grid? It would solve your problem and make it easier to manage/add to in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of organized markup and `border: dashed` or `border: dotted` for your little dots. You then float the price to the right and voila! easily reusable product-price relations!

## See the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A3tKF/3/

**HTML:**

```
<section class="productList">
    <div class="product">
        <span class="name">Example Product</span><span class="price">$2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <span class="name">Example Product</span><span class="price">$2</span>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.productList {
    width: 500px;
}
.product {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #aaa;
}
.product .name {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.product .price {
    float: right;
}
```

The most important part is in the CSS, specifically on the `.product` and `.product .price` rules:

- `border-bottom` sets the border under the element to a 1px dashed light gray
- `float` makes the element be aligned to the right and be more permissive about free space.